# Mapping links to components

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm learning to react and wanted to create a card that, when clicked, routes the user to an external web page. I haven't seen any tutorials or explanations on this all I keep finding is for internal website navigation. I tried doing this in different ways but can't find the correct way to do this.

my component:

```
    import React from "react";








function Card (props) {
 
  const handleClick = () => {
  return <a href={props.href} target= "_blank"></a>
  }

  return (
     
     <div>
     
    
}
        <div className="link-container" onClick= {()=> {
          return handleClick();}
        }>
          
        
        
            <div className="row">
                <div className="card">
                <hr className="divide"></hr>
                <img className="img" src={props.img} alt="social-icon" />
                <h4 className="name">{props.name}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            </div>
                     
     </div>

  )

}





export default Card;
```

href links to be used:

```
    const links = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Youtube",
        img:"./img/youtube1.svg",
        href: "https://www.youtube.com/c/SubwaySounds"

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Spotify",
        img:"./img/spotify.svg",
        href: "https://artists.spotify.com/c/artist/3DM32kjsG7Pp5EM7o3Uv7t/profile/overview"

    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Tiktok",
        img:"./img/tiktok.svg",
        href: "https://www.tiktok.com/@nysubwaysounds"

    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Instagram",
        img:"./img/Instagram1.svg",
        href: "https://www.instagram.com/nycsubwaysounds/?hl=en"

    },

    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Shop",
        img:"./img/shop.svg",
        href: "https://my-store-11524143.creator-spring.com/"

    }
    

]

export default links;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create an element for each item for the list. For this, you can use the builtin JS `map` function.

For example, you can create a new variable holding the elements:

```
const linksElements = links.map(item => (<Card item={item} />));
```

and use it with `{linksElements}` inside of the return value.

I've created this as an example using your list: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yt1hfl?file=src/App.js. Note that this is a quick and dirty implementation, without any other components.